# Multiple if statements, then, or else?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm having some problems getting a query to run based off another query. Here's the database diagram to give a little background. The primary keys for all the tables are automatically generated by identites. The first 2 insert statements (Donation and Food_Donation) work but I can't get the last insert into Donation_Details to work. Here's the code so far:

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection(DBcon)

Try
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("Insert into Donation (Donor_ID) VALUES ( " & txtDonNum.Text & "); Select @@Identity;")

    con.Open()
    command.Connection = con
    dr = command.ExecuteReader
    Dim Donation_ID As String = ""
    If dr.Read() Then
        Donation_ID = dr(0).ToString
        Dim food As New OleDbCommand("Insert into Food_Donation (Date_Received, Donation_ID) Values ( '" & maskedreceived.Text & "', " & Donation_ID & "); Select @@Identity")
        food.Connection = con
        food.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If

    Dim Food_ID As String = ""
    If dr.Read() Then

        Food_ID = dr(0).ToString
        Dim food2 As New OleDbCommand("Insert into Donation_Details (Quantity, Unit, Expiration_Date, Food_ID, Storage_ID, Type_ID) Values ( " & txtQuantity.Text & ", '" & boxUnit.Text & "', '" & maskedexpire.Text & "', " & Food_ID & ", " & txtStorageID.Text & ", " & txtTypeID.Text & ")")
        food2.Connection = con
        food2.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End If


Catch ex As Exception

    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Close()
End Try
```

End sub

I'm fairly correct my SQL statements are correct and it's just whether or not the last statements need to be an If or something else.

Comment: Little Bobby Tables would be proud. http://xkcd.com/327/. You should use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `dr = food.ExecuteReader()` rather than `food.ExecuteNonQuery()` if you want to reuse dr to acquire `Food_ID`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that you're using `If dr.Read()` twice.

The `dr.Read()` method will move the reader forward to the next row but you are only selecting a single value in your initial query.

So, for example, your reader (being made from the insert) will return a single row value for the successful insert. Calling `Read()` on it will succeed but then move the row cursor to `EOF` causing subsequent `Read()` calls to return `FALSE`